# mapboxgl.Marker how to remove

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

i'm use to

Reference  https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/drag-a-marker/

```
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
draggable: true
})
.setLngLat([0, 0])
.addTo(map);
```

how to remove marker?

```
 marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
                draggable: true,                
            })
                .setLngLat([0, 0])
                .addTo(map);
marker.remove() /// fail
```

i want remove marker

Answer (score 0):

```
marker.addTo(map).setLngLat([0, 0]).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer [here](https://vispad.blogspot.com/2019/05/mapbox-clear-all-current-markers.html) and it worked for me (there are other answers there too, but this is the only one that worked for me). If you pass an html element with a given className (in this case "marker") when you create new markers, you can remove them all with jquery like this.

```
import $ from 'jquery';

GeoJson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';
new mapboxgl.Marker(el).setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates).addTo(map);
});

$( ".marker" ).remove();
```